# How to search text/summary in JQL with "[]"

Tags: jql

Getting error while searching something like "[Title]".

I'm trying to search for issues with `summary ~ "[Title]"`, but getting the error `The text query '[Title]' for field 'summary' is not valid: probably your range query is incorrect.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug in jira: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-25092

Answer (score 2):

The "[" and "]" are special characters. See the confluence [Advanced searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/advanced-searching-939938733.html#Advancedsearching-restrictionsRestrictedwordsandcharacters) page. Escape the characters with a **double** backslash and it will work

```
summary ~ "\\[Title\\]"
```

Answer (score 0):

When searching a *text field* such as `summary` the list of special characters is different (to that mentioned in Jonathan's answer) see instead the 'Special characters' section on [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/search-syntax-for-text-fields-939938747.html) which is:

```
+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ~ * ? \ :
```

You *can* escape them with a double backslash but actually Jira will ignore them anyway:

> Special characters aren’t stored in the index, which means you can’t search for them. The index only keeps text and numbers, so searching for "\[Jira Software\]" and "Jira Software" will have the same effect — escaped special characters ([]) won’t be included in the search.

So it's simpler to just omit them. In python this can be done as follows:

```py
    safe_title = re.sub(r'[+\-&|!(){}\[\]^~*?\\:]', '',, title)
    jql = f'summary ~ "{safe_title}"'
```

EDIT: however, I did find that removing hyphens `-` could cause a false negative, e.g. if searching for a JIRA ticket with a hyphenated word like `foo-bar`, it will not be found if you search for `foo bar` so I ended up removing the `\-` from the above regex to avoid this problem.